# Filter GridView using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

I was thinking to apply a filtering function on GridView by using jQuery, such as a plugin called quickSearch. I have tried to google it but what i found is, normally the quickSearch is implemented together with table. So, for gridview, how can i filter the gridview using quickSearch??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. GridViews render as html tables so that plugin should probably do the trick.

Comment: actually, i have figured out implementing the jquery into the gridview. But now i found a new problem, the jquery only filter the 1st page of the gridview but not the others. Any idea?

Comment: it only filtered the first page because that is the only data that is on the user's page. jQuery runs on the client side and not server side.

Answer (score 0):

Very true, use a mix, depending on the data being displayed. If it is small result sets and I will be showing it all at once.